# TypeScript set type for array of objects causes problem when sorting with localCompare

Tags: javascript, typescript

I got a simple function with an array of objects. On this array there will always be at least one `string` property.

In the body I want to dinamically be able to select that `string` by `key` and order with `localCompare`.

The problem is that the properties can have `numbers` and when doing localCompare TS complains.

```js
;(() => {
  type entries = {
    [key: string]: string | number
  }


  const data: entries[] = [
    { key: 'bbb', number: 1 }, 
    { key: 'aaa', number: 2}
  ]
  // Let's imagine index comes as a parameter
  const index = 'key'
  const order: entries[] = data.sort((a, b) => a[index].localeCompare(b[index]))

  console.log(order)
})()
```

[Link to TS playground](http://tsplay.dev/WGk90W)

Comment: You've referred to the "first" property in the object in a few places in your question. Although it's true object properties have an order (now), it's almost never a good idea to rely on that order. If you want order, use an ordered data structure, like an array.

Comment: *"The problem is that the properties can have numbers and when doing localCompare TS complains."* What do you want to do when they're numbers?

Comment: Are all of the values of a given property the same type? I get that sometimes values are strings and other time numbers, but if `x` is a string for one of the array elements, will it reliably be a string for the other array elements?

Comment: @T.J Crowder I have re-edited the question

Comment: Unfortunately, `localCompare` only exists on strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, I think you're saying that **you** know that `a[index]` will always be a string because of logic in your code, but the problem is that TypeScript doesn't know that (because the object signature says it can be a string or a number).

To reassure TypeScript, you have at least a couple of choices:

#### Use a type assertion function:

```
function assertIsString(value: any): asserts value is string {
   if (typeof value !== "string") {
       throw new Error(`Expected a string, but got ${typeof value}`);
   }
}
```

Then:

```
const order: entries[] = data.sort((a, b) => {
    const avalue = a[index];
    const bvalue = b[index];
    assertIsString(avalue);
    assertIsString(bvalue);
    return avalue.localeCompare(bvalue);
});
```

[Updated playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6oKYCcoElUDKUWMYA5gBQBuyANiBgFwpgCeAlM2pjqojfQyIYfVMVJlEAbwCwAKESKYwRBSisADhjgqBDRAEIAvEcQAiMSXJn20+YoeKoACyxwA7ojAZPAUSxuWBQABr4AHlrQGAAmKIiWEgA0iABGIFCIZHAZACRS6lo6-HQMAL7B7ADc9oql8nVy8pUUFLZGAHx2CogFQhhg4hh8prLdigDaANYYrMwJ5AC6c+LkiAA+XiAAtinYNQ3yh920GBnRyFDIzP2DqOMLiKbjUojTs4gA5CnfH8lg27ssMwAIyIUrJF5vZgfZCw36bHbYZgAJlKCyOiggCDEwjA0QwYUenzeHxqWLAOLgWHxQMQNxIQ3uRPOlwAdKgqVAWshkik2p1Ro5MdiMsg9EJTMhxqR8WEFtUxg5yTiUuKiSlpXiCfKao5uNg8IQVpQxSUMFVdQ59Th8EQrJRVWaLYrFFhTiAsEhTYJWbQ4BA6BgAMJwLYaZBuiiOwTO2qxxDKuAnX1wShUmnsersVryIA)

This also has the advantage of giving you an explicit error if your code fails to ensure that the property name is only the name of a string property.

#### Use a type assertion

If you don't want the (very minimal) overhead of the assertion function, you can just override TypeScript:

```
const order: entries[] = data.sort((a, b) => (a[index] as string).localeCompare(b[index] as string));
```

[Updated playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/NwChEoAIF4D5IN4FgBQlIBcCeAHAppHgHYYBOAlngM4yKrroDaA1nlgFyRVnlEDmAXU7cK-SAB9IRAK4BbAEZ5S9SAF9UGlCoA2eDJAAmAQwxHOxHtUYDajBJFYdIAcnlvnAGilzFpTgEY1L3tHTmcjCM9vBSVOACZVAU10AGMAeyJuSF4DPAAPWmdHZxV0zP000ly-QhIKKxtoQxMjADoqSowwIy95KDhIECNGHPybIxoRXj5wVu00lKNdAGE02RwjUjwQeRGiXLzxyZ5+cHBgTVKMjt05tL4QSurwVFVwCFQgA)

#### Both

If you know your objects are homogenous, you can combine the two approaches, for instance using the assertion function just on the first entry:

```
if (data.length > 1) {
    assertIsString(data[0][index]);
}
const order: entries[] = data.sort((a, b) => (a[index] as string).localeCompare(b[index] as string));
```

[Updated playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6oKYCcoElUDKUWMYA5gBQBuyANiBgFwpgCeAlM2pjqojfQyIYfVMVJlEAbwCwAKESKYwRBSisADhjgqBDRAEIAvEcQAiMSXJn20+YoeKoACyxwA7ojAZPAUSxuWBQABr4AHlrQGAAmKIiWEgA0iABGIFCIZHAZACRS6lo6-HQMAL7B7ADc9oql8nVy8pUUFLZGAHx2CogFQhhg4hh8prLdigDaANYYrMwJ5AC6c+LkiAA+XiAAtinYNQ3yh920GBnRyFDIzP2DqOMLiKbjUojTs4gA5CnfH8lg27ssMwAIyIUrJF5vZgfZCw36bHbYZgAJlKCyOiggCDEwjA0QwYUenzeHxqylU50uADoTuQXIhOsDbKNHIpuNg8IQVpRKchxgAGBbjUj4sILKr7GpYsA4uBYfFAxA3EhDe5E3lU1ByqAtZDJFJtToUPkigkPNDxbnsGlwCB0DAAYTgWw0yCwGAoKWFeLNKFEVol3WlWpONsocoV7Hq7Fa8iAA)

That way you get a nice explicit error, but you don't have the overhead of checking during the `sort`.

Comment: Thanks, the assertion function is actually quite usefull as validation

Answer (score 3):

Just make sure you always convert the properties to strings:

```js
;(() => {
  type entries = {
    [key: string]: string | number
  }


  const data: entries[] = [
    { key: 2, number: 4 },
    { key: 'bbb', number: 1 }, 
    { key: 'aaa', number: 2}, 
    { key: 1, number: 3}
  ]

  const index = 'key'
  const order: entries[] = data.sort((a, b) =>
      `${a[index]}`.localeCompare(`${b[index]}`))

  console.log(order)
})()
```

Or, check the type of the values:

```js
;(() => {
  type entries = {
    [key: string]: string | number
  }


  const data: entries[] = [
    { key: 'bbb', number: 1 }, 
    { key: 'aaa', number: 2}
  ]

  const index = 'key'
  const order: entries[] = data.sort((a, b) => {
      const valA = a[index];
      const valB = b[index];

      return typeof valA === 'number' && typeof valB === 'number'
          ? valA - valB
          : `${valA}`.localeCompare(`${valB}`);
  });

  console.log(order)
})()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I dont want the `key` to ever be 2, it will always be a string

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I've updated my answer to make the comparer take that into account

Comment: @Álvaro See the edit.

Answer (score -2):

Your TS doesn't follow the TS guidelines.

Here I made a function `sortByProp`, which uses `keyof` so you can easily select the property you want to use for your sort.

You can try the code here: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLisFBvAsAKGWQGsIBPALmQGcxMQBzAbgKJAFcBbAI2io57RkAHxp1QzVsihwQAEwD2nAPxVuChQBsIslvgC+BAgHpjyAKrUIcmguQBJZAlnIYwTZCjIwACxSkyamRuMm8-bzIABxRHAHdZMAA6BxAw4CDnKzF6BhFkAV4oPTAolAAxd09rAGlyagAeABUAGgsAPmQAXmRsZABtAAVkUBJyBRhkRoBdKkbBqeQIAA9IeSDzZGVkIf4IADchfT6A8cmpvQIEBRBaZDk4MDgqdHEIPoXuvqlegKoAcm4gL+rQKfGQAEZkPpmt9RpRkH84EjgfkuIUqABmKEwwg9OH-ODcOAo0FQKgAJihBHORnwBBg7BACDAwGutigYAAQmQBlAFJEmq0ym0ABRwKBkybvVqRPmRKgVDzQGp1QXIYUASh6UmAExFJWip1l-K63T+tByfy1UAgYHYUFS4qgiWoCg5IrFrW4Ws6HTwuKIuuQYr6xsiC3qwVDcqm1tt9tSAFpwXoiIG9XBo-yFh1uFnw3G7Q6Iam0zai6kAAyl-Qa0vlhPIJ0ut1gD1PJsgMheqiyMg+jqZsMLRNR4d1giGOn4K43LQQRKaBQMEUAIgAyq3ubVKKvWq6Odzefz6i9MBB9+JGHlSaL7o9WquAquNROZ9dXdpF8u15vD2QADk0T4Pd2S5Hk5VPDAsEvHIb2AqA7weOBH1JF83yAA).

When I find out how to filter the types of properties, I will update the code again.

```
interface Entrie {
  key: string;
  number: number | string;
  random?: boolean;
}

// Used so I can filter the keys by the type I want. In this case string | number;
type FilteredKeys<T, U> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends U ? P : never }[keyof T];

const data: Entrie[] = [
  { key: 'bbb', number: 1 },
  { key: 'aaa', number: 3 },
  { key: 'aba', number: 2 }
];


function sortByProp<T, F>(arr: T[], prop: FilteredKeys<T, F>) {
  if (typeof prop == 'string') return arr.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[prop] < b[prop]) return -1;
    if (a[prop] > b[prop]) return 1;
    return 0;
  });
  return arr.sort((a: any, b: any) => a[prop] - b[prop]);
}

console.log("SortByKey:", sortByProp<Entrie, string | number>(data, "key"));
console.log("SortByNumber:", sortByProp<Entrie, string | number>(data, "number"));
```

Comment: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-BAA)

Comment: Here's a link to a playground where I use `keyof` so I can pick the property I want to sort by. Had to send it separately, as the link is so long. Will update my answer with the changes later, since I'm on my phone currently.

Comment: @Álvaro I updated my answer. Hopefully this version is more useful.